# Sparkling Water on Windows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, h2o

I'm using spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7 and sparkling-water-2.3.5 on Windows 10 64 bit.

I've taken the following steps and looking for help for the Steps 4 and 5.

Step 1: Run Spark shell by executing bin/sparkling-shell. Fine

Step 2: At scala prompt (Fine)

```
    scala> import org.apache.spark.h2o._
    scala> val h2oContext = H2OContext.getOrCreate(spark)
    scala> import h2oContext._
```

Step 3: - openFlow command at scala prompt to open Flow UI in the browser. Fine.

Step 4: At scala prompt (Not working)

```
    scala> openSparkUI command at scala prompt to open the Spark UI in the browser
    - error: not found: value openSparkUI
```

Step 5: Looking for an editor to write scala code and how to submit that code at scala prompt

Comment: I also tried it on window but later I found that SW doesn't work for windows.

Comment: @ManojKumarDhakd sparkling water should work on windows, if you have found a bug for sparkling water on windows please file it on the sparkling water github: https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/issues

Comment: @Lauren Actually,  around 8 months ego, I and my friend tried it in my office network at that time it doesn't work. I will try to use it on my PC.

Comment: The only editor I’ve ever been able to persally use for Scala is intellij with the Scala plugin.  The Scala type system is really complicated, and the code completion help from a really good editor is essential (as least to me).

Answer (score 0):

openSparkUI used to exist around 2015, but has since been removed. As noted in the question `h2oContext.openFlow` is still functional and an available option (type `q` to convert a cell to a scala cell in flow, type `h` to see the the full keyboard shortcut list - note: keyboard shortcuts only work if you are not in editor mode and typing within a cell).

Other possible interfaces for Scala code include Jupyter notebook and Zeppelin.